# possibility of adding a debugger to ace-editor

Tags: debugging, ace-editor

There is a way to add a debugger to ace editor, I mean add breackpoints to the gutter, highlight lines, go to next step etc..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but not very straightforward.

Cloud9 do this and the plugin code they use is available at: https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.run.debug

> The c9.ide.run.debug package offers a set of plugins that provide a generic, configurable and extendable user interface for step-through debuggers.

They talk more about it at: https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/debugger-plugin

Comment: Thank you. It was the answer